# Permission 'documentai.processors.processOnline' denied on resource (or it may not exist)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud-document-ai

I am trying to send a POST request to the Cloud Document AI API using Postman. I have tried sending a POST request with the API key included, along with providing an OAuth access token as the OAuth 2.0 Authorization (generated using gcloud auth application-default print-access-token). However, this error is returned:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission 'documentai.processors.processOnline' denied on resource '//documentai.googleapis.com/projects/<project id>/locations/us/processors/<processor id>' (or it may not exist).",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
        {
            "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
            "reason": "IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED",
            "domain": "documentai.googleapis.com",
            "metadata": {
                "resource": "projects/<project id>/locations/us/processors/<processor id>",
                "permission": "documentai.processors.processOnline"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I think this this a problem with the service account permission. If so, is there any way I can resolve this if I don't have the access to change roles?

Comment: Have yo followed the steps described in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/setup#auth) to authenticate your request? Which permissions did you assign to your service account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to give an update to this question. The problem was related to the service account permission. There is no way to resolve this without setting up your service account with the **correct permission**. Once you have correctly set up your service account, by using the service account key of said account, you should be able to resolve this problem.

TLDR; Follow the documentation (https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/setup#auth) properly. If you don't have access to the Google Account (like I did), try to get access to it. If not, I don't think there is another way around it.

Comment: You can also see the full list of IAM Permissions and IAM Roles for Document AI in the Documentation.

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/access-control/iam-permissions

https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/access-control/iam-roles

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this question as well. To resolve the issue, go to IAM roles and change the role of your service account to Document AI service user. The default is Document AI service Agent